# No que estou errando nesse Formulário que Calcule IMC em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, formulário

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function calcula_imc(){
        var altura = document.imcForm.altura.value;
        var peso = document.imcForm.peso.value;

         var quadrado = (altura*altura);

         var calculo = (peso/quadrado);
     }

       if (calculo<18.5){
           alert("Abaixo do Peso "+calculo);
       }
       else if (calculo>=18.6 && calculo<24.9){
           alert("Peso ideal (Parabéns) "+calculo);
       }
       else if (calculo>=25 && calculo<29.9){
           alert("Levemente acima do peso "+calculo);
       }
       else if (calculo>=30 && calculo<34.9){
           alert("Obesidade grau I "+calculo);
       }
       else if (calculo>=35 && calculo<39.9){
           alert("Obesidade grau II(Severa) "+calculo);
       }
       else if (calculo>40){
           alert("Obesidade grau III(Mórbida) "+calculo);
       }

   </script>
```

Comment: Fecha chaves no canto errado?

Answer (score 3):

A chave "}" que fecha a função está posicionada antes do término do conteúdo da função:

```
function calcula_imc(){
    var altura = document.imcForm.altura.value;
    var peso = document.imcForm.peso.value;

     var quadrado = (altura*altura);

     var calculo = (peso/quadrado);
 } <<---- fechamento da função
```

Coloque a chave no final do código para que todo seu conteúdo esteja dentro da referida função:

```
function calcula_imc(){
    var altura = document.imcForm.altura.value;
    var peso = document.imcForm.peso.value;

     var quadrado = (altura*altura);

     var calculo = (peso/quadrado);

   if (calculo<18.5){
       alert("Abaixo do Peso "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=18.6 && calculo<24.9){
       alert("Peso ideal (Parabéns) "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=25 && calculo<29.9){
       alert("Levemente acima do peso "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=30 && calculo<34.9){
       alert("Obesidade grau I "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=35 && calculo<39.9){
       alert("Obesidade grau II(Severa) "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>40){
       alert("Obesidade grau III(Mórbida) "+calculo);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cabe salientar que a pergunta foi editada, **não pelo autor**, e que pode mudar a interpretação da mesma.

Pergunta original:

> No que estou errando nesse Formulário que Calcule IMC em JavaScript
>
> **Exerc_2_Funcoes**

Se a intenção é usar duas funções `Exerc_2_Funcoes` chame a segunda função `result_imc()` ao executar a primeira função `calcula_imc()`.

```js
function calcula_imc(){
    var altura = document.imcForm.altura.value;
    var peso = document.imcForm.peso.value;

     var quadrado = (altura*altura);

     calculo = (peso/quadrado);
     //chama a função 
     result_imc();
}     

     
function result_imc(){
   if (calculo<18.5){
       alert("Abaixo do Peso "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=18.6 && calculo<24.9){
       alert("Peso ideal (Parabéns) "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=25 && calculo<29.9){
       alert("Levemente acima do peso "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=30 && calculo<34.9){
       alert("Obesidade grau I "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>=35 && calculo<39.9){
       alert("Obesidade grau II(Severa) "+calculo);
   }
   else if (calculo>40){
       alert("Obesidade grau III(Mórbida) "+calculo);
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="imcForm">
<input type="text" name="altura">
<input type="text" name="peso">
<input type="submit" onclick="calcula_imc()">
</form>
```

Comment: Só acho estranho essa comunicação via variável `calculo`, não me parece natural

Comment: Fique ciente de não declarar essa variável `calculo` para não dar erro :)